# Concurrent TCP connections in Linux

Tags: connection, load-balancing, tcp, rhel

I want to know whether I had hit the maximum number of connections that are allowed in my Linux based server

```
# netstat -an | grep -i time | wc -l
  1116
# netstat -an | grep -i estab | wc -l
  2137
```

TCP parameters at Kernel level are as follows:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
60
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

TIME_WAIT connections are from  the load balancer IP (199.X.X.02)

```
tcp   0   0 199.X.X.05:8280    199.X.X.02:51884     TIME_WAIT
```

How can I know whether I had hit the maximum limit? Any kernel parameters which will will tell me the current no of open connections. Also , how to calculate the maximum concurrent connections that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

"Any kernel parameters which will will tell me the current no of open connections".

Partial answer:
You should be able to see the list of your open sockets under /proc/PID/fd (where PID is you process' pid, of course).